# Remove part of filename with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, strip

I want to strip a filename like this:
IMG_6903.JPG&width=504

to:

IMG_6903.JPG

...

**My script looks like this:**

```
  $(function(){
    $('#exposure img').each(function(){
        var $imgSrc = this.src.split('&');
        $(this).wrap('<a rel="lightBox" />')
               .parent().attr("href", ""+$imgSrc);
      });
  });
```

But it doesn't work... How do I do this?

Comment: 3 correct answers in 4 minutes... WOW! time to accept one. :o)

Comment: just wondering, are you sure it is not `IMG_6903.JPG?width=504`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var imgSrc = this.src.substring(0,this.src.indexOf('&'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var andIndex = tmpString.indexOf('&');
tmpString = tmpString.substr(0, andIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

use **split**

```
var str = 'IMG_6903.JPG&width=504';
var array = str.split('&');
array[0];
```

array[0] will be IMG_6903.JPG

Answer (score 0):

You split the string but try using the array instead of the first element. Try this

```
 $(function(){
     $('#exposure img').each(function(){
         var $imgSrc = this.src.split('&');
         $(this).wrap('<a rel="lightBox" />')
             .parent().attr("href", "" + $imgSrc[0]);
     });
 });
```

Hope this helps.